# load video in shadowbox on page load

Tags: javascript, video, shadowbox

I need to load a video in shadowbox when the homepage loads. I need to know, what the code would be and specifically where the onload code would go to make this happen?

Answer (score 0):

Well, the actual details would depend on the shadowbox code you use. I'd recommend looking into Jquery as there are a number of shadowbox/lightbox plugins for it. For the actual video I assume you'll be using flash. If this is the case you'll also want to look into swfobject (which also has a good Jquery plugin) for handling the embedding.